# Looping through string - Adding and skipping characters

Tags: python-3.x, string, loops, iteration

I have the below code (which is wrong) and i would like to count the number of times the word "car" appears. So the output here would be 2.

```
word="cccccccaaaaaaaaaaarrrrrccar"
count=0
for letter in word:
        if letter == "c":
            if letter=="a":
                if letter=="r":
        count+=1

print(count)
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Please add some clarification: are you counting the number of times the exact string "car" is found, or the number of times there is a "c", followed by an "a", followed by an "r"?

Comment: Not the exact string "car". But how many times there is a sequence of "c" followed by "a" and then "r". But ultimately this would gives us how many "car" we have.

Comment: @DMach I believe a more precise statement is that you're looking for the number of times there's a 'c', then *only* one or more 'a', and then an 'r'. This would give a result of 2 with your sample `word` in your question. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, so the c's after the first "c" are ignored, the a's after the first "a" get ignored and then the r's after the first "r" get ignored.So in that way we get the "car"s

Comment: @DMach If the word is "cac" and the string is "cacac" - what should be the result?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I would not be interested in that.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, you can remove duplicate characters, join them using `str.join` and then use `str.count` to count the number of occurrences of the word "car":

```py
def remove_duplicate_characters(word):
    if word == "":
        return ""

    i = iter(word)
    prev = next(i)
    yield prev

    for ch in i:
        if ch == prev:
            continue
        prev = ch
        yield ch


word = "cccccccaaaaaaaaaaarrrrrccar"

print("".join(remove_duplicate_characters(word)).count("car"))
```

Prints:

```
2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
word="cccccccaaaaaaaaaaarrrrrccar"
i = 0
L = len(word)
while i < L:

    #Remove letter if the consecutive letters are same
    if word[i] == word[i-1]:
        word = word[:i] + word[i+1:]

        # As the letter deleted, the length reduces by 1 & i as well
        L = L - 1
        i = i - 1

    i += 1
count = word.count('car')
print(count) # Output : 2
```